# Tips for golfing in VBScript

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in VBScript? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to VBScript. Please post one tip per answer.

Thanks to Marcog for the original idea. :)

Comment: My friends would like this :)

Comment: Just in case anyone is editing vbs in notepad and just running the file - you can save yourself from having to see lots of `MsgBox`s by replacing the `MsgBox`s with `WScript.Echo`s and running the VBScipt file in cmd.exe with CScript (`CScript C:\filepath\file.vbs`)

Comment: Oh and you can add syntax highlighting for VBScript (or any VB derivative) using the markdown notation `<!-- language-all: lang-vb -->`

Answer (score 2):

Use an empty variable instead of ""

Uninitialized variables are set to a special value: empty.  When empty is cast to a string it becomes "".

Contrived example (using z instead of ""):

```vbs
s=InputBox(z)
For i=1To 5
    For j=1To i
        r=r&s
    Next
    MsgBox r
    r=z
Next
```

For numeric types Empty is 0, and for booleans it is false.  This can cut down on initialization code.

```vbs
a=inputbox("Enter Starting Value")
b=a
while done=0
    i=i+1
    b=b*2
    done=(b>10000 or i>10)
wend
msgbox "Your "&a&" rabbit(s) have turned into "&b&" rabbit(s) in "&i&" years."
```

Answer (score 1):

### Shorter `IF` `Then`: save 10 bytes

If you terminate an IF/THEN clause with a carriage return, you don't need to use an END IF.

Example:

```vbs
For x=1 to 1
  IF x=1 THEN MSGBOX "No Error"
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use IIf instead of If...Then

`IIf()` is essentially a ternary operator. You can potentially save quite a few bytes.

For example:

```vbs
var = "World"

If foo Then
    MsgBox "Hello" & var
Else
    MsgBox "Goodbye" & var
End If
```

Vs.

```vbs
MsgBox IIf(foo, "Hello", "Goodbye") & "World"
```

Note: VBA only. VBScript doesn't support this one.

Comment: `Iff()` isn't an intrinsic VBScript function, thus it's not supported.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. I can't believe I never knew knew that. [You're right.](http://m.windowsitpro.com/scripting/vbscript-iif-function) I'm going to leave it here because the tip will be useful for vba folks.

Comment: Unfortunately `Iff()` isn't an intrinsic VBA function as well :D

Comment: Yes it is. Oh. Lol. Damned typo.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Line Separators

Newlines count as two bytes ("\n"), but a colon is only one.

```vbs
For i = 0 To 10
    MsgBox "Hello"
Next
```

Vs.

```vbs
For i = 0 To 10: MsgBox "Hello": Next
```

*Note: You can't use the line separator for `If` statements.*

Comment: Newlines only count as one byte on Unix Systems, however, Windows Systems use `\r\n` (Which is two bytes, 13 and 10 respectively)

Answer (score 0):

## Condense `For` statements

In `For` statements (and in fact any statement comprised of a `"` or numeric literal followed by a reserved command) the space that separates any numeric and a following word may be removed

This means that

```vb
For i = 1 To 100 Step 2
...
Next
```

May be condensed down to

```vb
For i=1To 100Step 2
...
Next
```

and following this logic,

```vb
If t = "TEST" Then ...
```

may be condensed to

```vb
If t="Test"Then ...
```